# How to retrieve the item id-attributes value from string-array in string resource file in android

Tags: android, xml

I have a situation that I need to pass the value of id attribute mentioned in code, but it always gives position instead of its true value

I made a model class and used getId() method to retrieve but its returning the position only

In above code I have given id to item attribute and I want the value of it in my java file which should be 22,24 accordingly rather than 1,2(its positions)

Comment: <string-array name="department">
        <item>--Select Type--</item>
        <item id="22">Garden</item>
        <item id="34">Gym</item>
    </string-array>

Comment: Add code in question instead of posting in comment.

Comment: Please provide the code you have written, that is giving errors. Read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) before posting.

Comment: I tried but the stackOverflow didn't let me add it